# Is regex the best approach for this?

Tags: python, regex

Im looking to match an item from a list and place that item into a variable. Below is what I have put together so far, but currently Im not sure how to create the regex I need to match just the 1 item and I am not sure if this is the best approach. I am trying to match the item in the list with '/site-packages' on the end.

**Test Data** (output from sites)

```
['/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.9/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages', '/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.9/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/site-python', '/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages']
```

**Code**

```
import site
import re
sites = site.getsitepackages()
print sites
site = re.compile('*/site-packages')

for item in sites:
    m = site.search(item)
    if m:
        print m
```

Comment: Shouldn't you have `.*` there instead of `*`?

Answer (score 5):

In this case you could also use the string `in` operator in a list comprehension

```
m = [i for i in sites if r'/site-packages' in i]
```

Similarly you could use `endswith`

```
m = [i for i in sites if i.endswith(r'/site-packages')]
```

**Edit**
To get the smallest element (by length) once the list comprehension has executed you can do

```
min(m, key=len)
```

Comment: Ha, no need for regex in this case. even better thank you CoryKramer. Is there away to check for the shortest `len` in the same comprehension ? Ie I want to return a single item with the shortest length

Comment: Within the list comprehension, no. But you can do so as a step afterwards, see my edit.